# Using my websites link in a href is preventing me from receiving my message

Tags: php, gmail, html-email

I am trying to send a message using php mail fucntion. This is a part of the message that is causing the issue.

a href="http://www.MYWEBSITE.com">Visit

Mail is returning with a 1 but I am not seeing the message in my inbox. If I change it to

a href="http://www.google.com">Visit

I receive the message in my inbox.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Spam, spam, spam, or maybe spam. Pick any 3.

Comment: I have nothing in my spam folder though.

Comment: Use a mail class to send emails like PHPMailer or SwiftMailer.

Comment: Then check your mail server's logs to see what happened to the email. Once PHP hands it over to the mail server, it's done and can say "true". after that it's ENTIRELY up to the mail system to actually deliver it.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of what's spammy in your MIME header and html content, or if your sender isn't trusted. It mainly checks against SpamAssassin, which has most of the rules of other email filters.

http://isnotspam.com/